# What's the difference between findAndModify and findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: mongodb

It seems they are the same. But is there any really difference between the two? The only obvious thing is of the `findOneAndUpdate()` which will only match to one document.

Answer (score 8):

Besides what you mentioned, the most conspicuous difference is:

`findOneAndUpdate` allows for just updates - no deletes or replaces etc.

`findAndModify` can do a lot more including replace, delete and so on. It combines the functionality of three DML operations: *update*, *delete*, *replace*. So it can be used as such.

*Disadvantage* is that it is prone to errors precisely because it combines three DML operations.

Similarities:

- They both operate on a single document
- And return that updated document - provided it could match one

History:

`findOneAndUpdate`, `findOneAndReplace`, `findOneAndDelete` are the 3 more recent methods introduced in version 3.2 of the shell to circumvent the issues mentioned above with `findAndModify`.

Answer (score 7):

findOneAndUpdate updates the very first document based on the filter criteria.
With findAndModify you can do a lot more. You can update as well as remove the documents matching the filter criteria. Please have a look at below links for more details:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/